# Update a column with information from 3 other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Now I have one table, let's say table PROPERTY, which have 2 columns called A and B,

```
A B     PIVOT  
1 dog   T  
2 cat   T  
1 chien F  
1 gou   F  
2 chat  F  
2 miao  F
```

Now I want to add one column C, whose content is based on A and B, and is indexed by 1.  that's to say,

```
A B     C  
1 dog   dog  
2 cat   cat  
1 chien dog  
1 gou   dog  
2 chat  cat  
2 miao  cat
```

How can I do this? This is a large table(200k rows)

I was thinking about:

```
UPDATE PROPERTY a SET C= 
     (select min(b.B) from CFG_DIM_PROPERTY b where 
          b.A=  a.A and b.PIVOT= 'T')
```

However, this sql has taken too much time. Do you smart guys know other ways? And some indications about how you thought of it?

Comment: What is the function of the `PIVOT` column?

Comment: When PIVOT is T(true), means that C will be based on this row's B column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use **merge**:

```
merge into PROPERTY t
using (select min (b) as min_b, a
       from CFG_DIM_PROPERTY b
       where b.pivot = 'T'
       group by a) t1
on (t.a = t1.a)
when matched then
    update set t.c = t1.min_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want output like this? Because your table doesn't have a column `c` yet. And if you want to add it, you can use below logic to get its value.

Also note that if for each `A`, if there are more than 1 `PIVOT1` as `T`, then you can get unexpected result.

```
    with tbl(A,B,PIVOT1) as(  
    select 1,'dog  ','T' from dual union all   
    select 2,'cat  ','T' from dual union all   
    select 1,'chien','F' from dual union all   
    select 1,'gou  ','F' from dual union all   
    select 2,'chat ','F' from dual union all   
    select 2,'miao ','F' from dual
    )
    select t1.a,t1.b,t2.b as C from tbl t1 left join
    (select a,b from tbl where pivot1='T') t2
    on t1.a=t2.a
```

Output:

```
  A  B       C
  1  gou    dog  
  1  chien  dog  
  1  dog    dog  
  2  miao   cat  
  2  chat   cat  
  2  cat    cat
```

Comment: Thanks Utsav, I tried with your codes second part and it works fine. Thought I have to still figure out how to update it to C column.. And I didn't understand the dual union all part ....

Comment: The subquery factoring clause (`WITH table_name ( column_name, ... ) AS ( ... )`) is just providing a mock-up of your data without having to create the underlying table - as you have that table already you can omit that bit of the query.

Comment: Thanks MT0 ^^ That's very helpful!

Comment: For this method, is there a way to update and put the values into a column called C quickly (rather than just do a select) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE PROPERTY p
SET    c = ( SELECT b
             FROM   PROPERTY v
             WHERE  p.a       = v.a
             AND    v."PIVOT" = 'T'
             AND    ROWNUM    = 1   -- This line may not be necessary if there
                                    -- is only ever one 'T' per 'A'
           );
```

Comment: Hi MT0, I don't see there is a difference between your time and the time my SQL will take. Point out if I'm wrong...

Comment: There is no `GROUP BY` and the correllated sub-query can stop when it finds the first row (using `ROWNUM=1`). You can check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see the difference between the queries.

Comment: Oh thanks, I just checked `ROWNUM`, yes you are right, but it still takes a long time. :)